# Не удается выполнить PHP скрипт через ВКонтакте

Tags: actionscript, vkontakte-api, php, вконтакте

Дело в том, что запуская со своей машины, все нормально, код PHP выполняется, а после запуска с контакта скрипт не выполняется. В чем дело понять не могу.

```
import vk.APIConnection;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.events.*;

var flashVars: Object = stage.loaderInfo.parameters as Object;

if (!flashVars.api_id) 
   flashVars['viewer_id'] = 66748;

var VK: APIConnection = new APIConnection(flashVars);

sendData(new URLVariables("userID=" + flashVars.viewer_id), addSuccess);

function sendData(vars:URLVariables, onSuccess:Function):void
{
   var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
   request.url = "http://matchthree.url.ph/save1.php/";
   request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
   request.data = vars;

   var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
   loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
   loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSuccess);

   loader.load(request);
}

function addSuccess(e:Event):void
{
   txt.text = "Успешно";
}
```

PS: Первый раз работаю с ВКонтакте API.

Comment: @samoilow, на хосте (вашем) есть `crossdomain.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решается добавлением файла crossdomain.xml на сервер с содержанием:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Спасибо, [[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow).
PS: Не люблю незакрытых вопросов.